# Do you think a program could understand our world and explore beyond?

Tags: artificial-intelligence

New to StackExchange !

The question is very abstract, sorry for that.

I was wondering if it was possible for a program to understand our world. What I mean by "understand" is that it could have a way of saving information about the reality and manipulate them.

The information that it would uses are facts, because the information need to be true, concise and light.

If this program could exists we could use it to solve problems. Because it knows every important facts, it could take everything in account and solve the problem in the better way possible.

So do you think this is possible ?

Comment: Is this a philosophical question: "Is it possible for a computer program to understand anything at all?" or is this a computer science question, "Is it possible for a computer program to be a universal problem solver?"

Comment: I think it's inevitable. The real issue is whether we can coexist with it/them.

Comment: @DavidGudeman Here the question is more about the computer science field.

Comment: "Because it knows every important facts" ... In the early days of AI, the 1960's and 70's, the idea was to give computers a knowledge base of facts about the world, from which it would reason. That approach failed. What they do now is sophisticated data mining on large data sets on which the neural nets are trained. So you don't tell it what a cat is. You show it a million pictures of cats and let the neural net figure out on its own what a cat is. In no case is there "understanding," but the point is that fact-based AI was tried and we don't do that anymore. Unless someone brings it back.

Comment: @user4894 Teaching kids in schools doesn't go so well either. Apprenticeship works best. And start as early as possible, look at S. Williams. I wonder if she ever had a physics class on tennis balls? Wouldn't have helped.